# Interface with properties of another interface's property

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums, interface

Just like in the title. Is it possible?
for example:

```
interface Data {
    operationNumber: number,
    type: string,
    text: string
}

const aaa = {
  operationNumber: 209,
  type: "click",
  text: "clicked"
}
```

and I want to get something like this:

```
const bbb = {
  "209": {operationNumber: 209, type: "click", text: "clicked"}
}
```

How should I create interface for `bbb`? I don't want to create something like this:

```
interface Something {
  209: Data,
  210: Data,
  211: Data... etc.
}
```

Comment: Does `bbb` have fixed keys? What could the keys look like?

Comment: My initial impression is an array would be a better data structure for `bbb`. You can then type it as `Array<Data>`.

Comment: `interface Something { [index: number]: Data }`? (Also works with an enum for the operation numbers instead of `number`)

Comment: Bergi, that looks familiar, probably that's what I've been looking for. I will check it as soon as possible and let you know, thanks.
Wing, using array I'm gonna loose "keys" which are important for me

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Bergi, that was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks again.